# Do I need to use finish() for task listener

Tags: android

I look at some example codes for the task and found out they have finish() inside
OnSuccessListener () and OnFailureListener (). Is this a normal practice? Even without finish(), it still works fine.

The reason I ask is because I put the task inside my SubActivity. It's called by the MainActivity by intent. If I put finish() inside task listener, it will also let it go back to MainActiviy and that's not my intention.

Comment: The question is not clear. "it will also let it go back to MainActiviy and that's not my intention" - then what is your intention?

Comment: I just want to stay in the SubActivity and let the task finish.

Answer (score 0):

`finish()` method is a signal of normal termination to an activity. Meaning that it will invoke `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroy` and return to the previous existing activity (if any) or terminate the application if it is the last activity.

You do not have to use, examples that use `finish()` in some callbacks they are calling it simply because they are done and want to return to previous activity in the stack.

Comment: Thanks MoGa. That answers my question.